# Python optimisation problem under constraints with scipy

Tags: python, function, optimization, scipy, constraints

I have an optimisation problem but I am not sure if i can resolve it thanks to scipy. Here is the problem :
the input of my problem is the tuple (x,y)

I have a function **f : (x,y)** and another **g : (x,y)**

I need to minimize f and to assure g(xopt,yopt) = 0, is that possible ?

Despite my research, i did not find a way to solve this problem with scipy.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found an answer to my problem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iSnTtV6b0Gw